# How to set default values for "modify entity values" form

Tags: views

I have a [view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) with nodes and a [views bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) field. With this vbo field I like to "modify entitity values" of the selected node.

Is it possible:

- to automatically check the checkbox for a selected field, so that the field to modify the value is shown by default?
- to automatically set a default value in the textfield (which should be shown by default of course)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook the form, which is shown after clicking "Modify entity values".

Here is my code to handle this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  global $user;
  $account = user_load($user->uid);

  //to get the form id, you have to print it out first
  dpm($form_id);

  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'views_form_your_view_display_name':

      $nid_page = menu_get_object();

      // the next line activates the checkbox to show the input field
      $form['bundle_item']['show_value']['field_name']['#default_value'] = TRUE;

      // the next line sets the default value for the field shown
      // notice: the 'value' array field depends on the field type and may also
      // be 'target_id' (for entity references) or 'tid' for taxonomy references
      $form['bundle_item']['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $your_desired_value;
  }
}
```

Comment: There's actually a [hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views_bulk_operations%21views_bulk_operations.api.php/function/hook_views_bulk_operations_form_alter/7) which could simplify your code a bit.