# vbo action to reset back to default value

Tags: tokens, views

Text field's default value is set using [field_default_token](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_default_token) and it is working fine. There are several nodes present prior adding default value and needs to be set in bulk(no input is required again as value is already available in field settings).For this how I can use VBO.
default value for field in field instance is set to

```
[node:field-year][node:nid]
```

Referred [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/124700/19205) for code

```
$form['bundle_item']['field_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = <how to get default token here>
```

**Update:**
another example

1. Let say there is a content type Professors with basic fields like name,expertise_in etc and some contents are created with these fields.
2. Later another field is added called Prefix whose default value is set to *Dr.* From now onwards all new content created will have the prefix field value set to Dr and thats fine. Now I want to set value of Prefix(which are empty) for the contents created in step 1 but without giving user option to set value of prefix instead it should retrieve default value which is set in the Prefix field settings ie *Dr*.

Comment: What do you mean by "default" in this context? Is is the default value for the field instance you're looking for?

Comment: @Clive yea I think he means Field Instance default value. AFAIK there's no such default bulk operation.

Comment: @kiranking You probably want to read [VBO Dev Guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067)

Comment: @Clive yes field's default value which was set in field's settings page. Updated question with another simple example.